# Define pointtype using `word` command in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting several datafiles using the same linestyle (`ls 1`). However, I would like to differentiate the data using different pointtypes contained in `wrd_pt` on the code below.

The result is shown in the figure, where GNUPLOT plots as pointtype the values contained into the variable `wrd_pt` instead of the symbols (square, triangle, ...) associated with each numbers. I am using `GNUPLOT 5.0` and there is no way I can update it (I am not the sudoer of the computer I am using) to use arrays for e.g. of the version 5.2.

Does anyone knows how I can fix that?

```
[... initializing ...]
wrd_pt ="5 7 9 11 13 15"
[... some other piece of code ...]
set output "plot_1a.eps"
    plot for [i=1:words(fspo_one)] work_dir.word(fspo_one, i) u 1:5 w lp ls 1 pt word(wrd_pt, i) ps 1 notitle
unset output
```

[image: Result of the code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using plotting style `with labels`? Works also with gnuplot 5.0.

Something like this:

**Code:**

```
### point types as string from a string
reset session

wrd_pt = "5 7 9 11 13 15"

set xrange[0:10]
set style textbox opaque

set samples 10
plot for [i=1:words(wrd_pt)] '+' u 1:(i*$1**2) w l lw 2 notitle, \
     for [i=1:words(wrd_pt)] '+' u 1:(i*$1**2):(word(wrd_pt,i)) w labels boxed notitle

### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hooh! I did not think about that. Great.